# Spring boot ssl configuration broken after upgrade to 1.4.0 from 1.3.x

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot

I am having an issue with ssl configuration, my configuration is as follows:

```
server.port=8449
# self signed cert with CN=localhost used for https method tests
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=some-alias
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
```

If used with 1.3.7 version of spring boot everything is working. If upgraded to 1.4.0 on client side I get:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:448)
```

And calling ssl port from chrome results:

The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or    cipher suite. This is likely to be caused when the server needs RC4, which is no longer considered secure.

Similar error from Firefox as well.

As I said only thing different in configuration is spring boot version. Am I missing something in configuration so it could be used with newer version of spring boot?

Thanks in advance
Cheers!

P.S. I am not very knowledgeable in ssl related topics so please try to explain it for somewhat simple.

Comment: You shouldn't need to configure SSL differently in 1.4. I've just tried [Boot's Tomcat SSL sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-ssl) and it works with both Safari and Chrome. Can you provide a small sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the sample link, it helped me solve the problem :) Issue was with how it was configured, with Tomcat 8.0.x the configuration worked just fine, but with Tomcat 8.5.4 it seems (maybe I am wrong about this) that you need to specify key-store-password explicitly and not just key-password as it was in my example.

Comment: I have a very similar problem, when upgrading Spring Boot from 1.3 to 1.4, I have lost all the ECDHE ciphers, I am only left with the DHE ones. If I downgrade Tomcat to 8.0.x, things works again. I specify both keystore and key passwords to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue thanks to this [Boot's Tomcat SSLsample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-ssl) provided by [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson)

```
server.port=8449
# self signed cert with CN=localhost used for https method tests
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=some-alias
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
```

My guess (I could be wrong about this) is that Tomcat 8.5.4 requires specified `server.ssl.key-store-password=password` it's not enough with just the `server.ssl.key-password` being specified so after updating the configuration I came up with something like this:

```
server.port=8449
# self signed cert with CN=localhost used for https method tests
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-alias=some-alias
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
```

And now it works as intended :) 
Hope this answer helps someone else.

P.S. Yeah, I know it's bad to use the same password for both specific key and the general store, but this is just a test key store.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this. I tend to forget how I create the keystore and that there are actually two different passwords, also if the password for the keystore is wrong there is an exception but if the other one is missing there is no warning, no error, nothing in the logfiles.

Answer (score 0):

For me everything was working on my local machine, but when I tried running the Spring Boot Server on my Linux server (Amazon AWS EC2), I got the same error. I did not get this error when using Spring Boot 1.3.x.

I was able to solve this issue by installing Oracle JDK instead of the Open JDK that was pre-installed on the server.

This is the guide I followed: https://gist.github.com/rtfpessoa/17752cbf7156bdf32c59